# subclassing static control to receive WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to make the background of a static control that displays text transparent. After 2 days of excessive googling i've come up with this:

```
class TLABEL : public TWINDOW {
private:
    HINSTANCE hInst;
public:

    static LRESULT CALLBACK SubclassCallback(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR userdata)
    {
        TLABEL* pThisWindow = (TLABEL*)userdata;

        //look for messages that we want to process ourselves
        switch (msg)
        {
            //make background transparent
            case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
            {
                HDC hDC = (HDC)wParam;

                SetBkMode(hDC, TRANSPARENT);
                SetTextColor(hDC, RGB(0, 0, 0)); //text color black

                MessageBox(NULL, L"WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC", L"Error!",MB_ICONEXCLAMATION|MB_OK);

                return (LRESULT)GetStockObject(NULL_BRUSH);
            }

            case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            {
                return TRUE;;
            }

            //remove Subclass if window is destroyed
            case WM_NCDESTROY:
            {
                RemoveWindowSubclass(pThisWindow->handle, &TLABEL::SubclassCallback, uIdSubclass);
                return TRUE;
            }

        }

        //deliver all other messages to the original callback-function
        return DefSubclassProc(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }

    //standard alignment left
    explicit TLABEL(int nx, int ny, int nwidth, int nheight, HWND hParent)
    {
        hInst = GetModuleHandle(NULL); //i know this is a bad practice
        handle = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TRANSPARENT,  //background transparent
                                L"STATIC", L"",  //class name + text
                                WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_LEFT,  //styles
                                nx, ny, nwidth, nheight,  //dimensions
                                hParent, NULL, hInst, NULL);

        //subclass window to catch messages we want to process ourselves
        SetWindowSubclass(this->handle, &TLABEL::SubclassCallback, 0, (DWORD_PTR)this);
    }
```

Somehow the SubclassCallback()-function never receives a WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message, but i know that the function is called and that it receives WM_ERASEBKGND messages just fine. If i handle the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message in the message-handler of the main-window it works, unfortunately that would negate all benefits that come with making a seperate class for such a static control

I have not found any hints why the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message is sent to the main window and not my static control since all examples seem to do it just like that.

i have compiled it under VS2010 Express on a WinXP-32 machine

Comment: That message is sent to the parent of the control, most controls were designed to be used as-is in a dialog template with the dialog window customizing their look.  C++ class wrappers use tricks like sending it back so the control can handle the message itself and implement properties like Fore/BackColor.  Best to not re-invent that wheel btw.

Comment: The docs for [`WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) state that "A static control, or an edit control that is read-only or disabled, **sends the WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC message to its parent window** when the control is about to be drawn. " I would not change this behavior, but if you still wish to along your way then you should handle `WM_ERASEBKGND` in my opinion. HTH. Best regards.

Comment: As others said that message is sent to the parent control because in the old days with C and dialogs it was easier to get the job done that way. Today object oriented frameworks usually send such messages back to the control (this is usually mentioned as "reflecting back" in the literature) object to be able to write reusable control classes. If some events of the control can not be handled in the class of the control then you simply can not write a reusable control in an object oriented framework.